# Can CiviRules assign an activity?

Tags: activities, civirules

I am successfully triggering on "Activity is added; Trigger for Activity Source" and updating the status of the activity. Now I need to assign the activity to the Source contact in the activity so they get the email notification with the activity details. Can't find an action to do that. I can send an email, but that lacks all the activity's details.

Comment: The Add Action > Select Action dropdown has an option for "Activity Contact Record Type (Assignee, Source or Target)" which maybe relates to this. Unfortunately selecting it results in error "Not a valid action, action class is missing."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is an action yet to do what you want it to do. It is not a complicated action though, so it should be relatively easy to add. Do you have any PHP skills? If so, it would be great if you could do a PR and add the action? There is documentation on how to create an action here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-action/

Comment: Ok, I'll pit my limited skills at it.

Comment: You're right, simple enough. I'll submit a PR soon. Unfortunately it didn't accomplish my end goal. Turns out that assigning an activity via the API (v3) does NOT send the assignee the nice email they get when the assignment is via GUI.

Comment: Erik - ask @jaapjansma who helped me with https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1767. I am not conversant in git. This time I think I managed to get my changes into a clone of civirules - https://lab.civicrm.org/SRQ_civicrm/civirules. I can't, however, figure out how to create a PR! Would appreciate any help/guidance you can offer.

Comment: You could potentially send the message from your action using  the Email API?

Comment: In your fork, got to the + in the top blue bar. There will be an option to create a new merge request?

Comment: Re. the email, I found that webform-civicrm used CRM_Case_BAO_Case::sendActivityCopy() so mimicked that.
Re. the merge request, many thanks for the instructions. I created https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/merge_requests/72.

Comment: I have merged the Merge Request. Thanks!